# self.tableView is nil and different from the tableview that is calling numberOfSectionsInTableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView. When the view loads, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` gets called, and I expect at that time for my `self.numberOfSections` variable to be 0. Then when I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the completion block of loading my data, it does not call any UITableViewDataSource methods.

After some debugging, I have found that even when `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is called right when the view loads, that if I print the `tableView` passed into the method, it is different than the nil `self.tableView`.

I am almost positive that all of my outlets are hooked up properly (I followed the same patterns I use for every other table view I make). So I am not sure what is causing this to happen, and what table view is even being passed in to `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` if my `self.tableView` instance is nil?

The screenshot below shows a breakpoint in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and print-outs of the instances.
[image]

Comment: How are you setting your tableView property? Can you show a screenshot of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

in .h:

```
  @interface YourViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

in .m :

```
    YourTableView.delegate = self;
    YourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

tableView delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return numberofRowsYouWant;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    // make your cell.....

    return cell;

}
```

If you don't miss any step of these, it should work correctly !
Of course if you use IB, don't forget to connect your tableView with the IBOutlet !

You can reload your tableView for example a method like this:

```
-(void) showData
{
    [YourTableView reloadData];
    [YourTableView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the answer, but this doesn't fill my needs. my number of sections is variable and i am using interface builder so i don't need to set dataSource and delegate programmatically because they are hooked up in IB.

Comment: where do you set this variable? in an other viewController? or in the same?

Comment: in another method, but that is kind of irrelevant to the fact that my IBOutlet self.tableView is nil.

Comment: try to clean your project ( shift + cmd + k ), and delete from simulator, restart simulator, and xcode , or your mac. Sometimes Xcode became dumb, and set @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView; not strong because it's an outlet

Comment: good call. not sure why i didn't reset before. i also remove DerivedData when cleaning up like that just in case. thanks!

Comment: sorry, but your answer was not correct. the answer you laid out was not relevant to my issue. the issue was with the simulator cache, not my tableview implementation.